# Parallel big matrix multiplication

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I need to multiply two big matrices `A` and `B` as follow:

```
library(bigmemory)
library(bigalgebra)
library(biganalytics)

A <- big.matrix( replicate(100,  rnorm(10^5)) )
B <- big.matrix( replicate(10^5, rnorm(100))  )
AB <- A %*% B
```

How could I compute this multiplication in parallel?

The only tutorial I've come across so far is [this one](http://illposed.net/boston_r_meetup_2012.pdf):

```
> library("doRedis")
> registerDoRedis(queue="example")
> L = foreach(j=1:2,.packages="VAM",.combine=c) %dopar%
+ {
+ key = paste("X",j,sep="")
+ ridx = ((j-1)*5 + 1):min((j*5),nrow(A))
+ X = A[ridx,] %*% B[,]
+ Y = as.big.matrix(X,backingfile=key)
+ vnew(Y, key)
+ key
+ }
> X = vam(matrix(L,nrow=2))
> sum(X[,] - A[,] %*% B[,])
[1] 0
```

But I'm not sure how to put it into practice. There may also be a simpler/more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Don't try to implement this yourself. There are some optimized parallel matrix libraries out there that you can use in R. Which OS do you have?

Comment: @F.Privé I have Windows 10.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this on WIndows is to use [Microsoft R Open](https://mran.microsoft.com/download). See [the benchmarks](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread).

Comment: @F.Privé Thank you for the advice, I am not familiar with Microsoft R Open. Is there any major drawback of using it compared to R?

Comment: It should be compatible. Look at their website. I think in RStduio, you can even choose which version you want to use (R ou MRO) in options.

Comment: @F.Privé I'll have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: I would add to @F.Privé to note that Microsoft R Open doesn't have parallel functions for `big.matrix` objects.  I would love to learn otherwise.

Comment: @cdeterman From what I understand, {bigalgebra} uses the same matrix library as R. Then, if this library is the MKL provided by MRO, then the multiplication provided by {bigalgebra} is faster and parallelized.

Comment: @F.Privé hmm... I'm not sure.  I initially created my development version of `bigalgebra` where I was leveraging the underlying C++ Armadillo library to switch between different matrix libraries.  The current version of `bigalgebra` only uses R's matrix library.  Would be interesting to look at some benchmarks.  This should likely be taken off this comment section though.

Comment: @cdeterman Look at the results we got with the OP.

Comment: @F.Privé I am very happy to see that.  Very happy to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Microsoft R Open, I go from 3 sec to 0.1 sec!

```
library(bigmemory)
library(bigalgebra)

N <- 200
M <- 1e5

A <- big.matrix(N, M, init = rnorm(N * M))
B <- big.matrix(M, N, init = rnorm(N * M))
system.time(AB <- A %*% B)
```

[image: Change the version of R you use in RStudio settings (need to quit RStudio afterwards)]

Comment: Just incredible! I tried with `N <- 300` and `M <- 1e6`: it took 74.04 sec under R.3.5.1, whereas it took 15.9 sec under MRO 3.5.1. Thank you!

Comment: Does it still makes sense to explicitly compute in parallel operation (e.g. with `furrr` or `foreach` packages) under MOR or is everything already computed in parallel by default?

Comment: Nop, do NOT parallelize yourself.

Comment: it seems bigalgebra is currently discontinued. Any alternative?

Comment: See https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/issues/133 and https://privefl.github.io/bigstatsr/articles/bigstatsr-and-bigmemory.html.